# Zero-Padding TimeSpan.ToString(String)

Tags: c#, formatting, timespan

I'd like to create a string from a TimeSpan object that has the format: "hhhh:mm:ss.ff".

When I use the following, I get a FormatException ...

```
private const string MAX_TIME_ALLOWED_FORMAT = @"hhhh\:mm\:ss.ff";

String myDurationSring = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(myDurationInSeconds).ToString(MAX_TIME_ALLOWED_FORMAT) : string.Empty;
```

Does my format string need some work or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: D Stanley's answer is what I'd go for, but what was causing the exception is the "." in the format string - it also needs a "\" before it.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin Even fixing that will result in an exception as it's not a valid format string.

Comment: @DStanley Ahh, I forgot I'd also removed the first two 'h's when I tested it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TimeSpan.ToString` does not support a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) that shows total hours  - it can only show the hour *portion*, which has a max value of 23.

I'd use a format string that takes the individual components of the `TimeSpan`:

```
String myDurationSring =
    string.Format("{0:0000}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                  (int)(ts.TotalHours), 
                  ts.Minutes, 
                  ts.Seconds, 
                  ts.Milliseconds/10.0);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest and cleanest way is with an interpolation:

```
var myDurationSring = $"{ts.Hours:0000}:{ts.Minutes:00}:{ts:Seconds:00}.{ts.Milliseconds/10.0}";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
"hhhh:mm:ss.ff"
```

As the format string. I assume you're trying to escape the colons. You don't need to. If you need the colons in the output try:

```
"hhhh\\:mm\\:ss.ff"
```

Comment: `TimeSpan` requires that separators be included as string literals, hence the necessary escape characters.